# Render HTML Symbols

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I created a `Symbol` component in React to easily render [HTML Symbols](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_symbols.asp) by name like `euro` will render `&euro;`(€) or `sum` render `&sum;`(∑).

Issue is that if I just render the HTML code I will see the code on the screen and not the symbol. So I had to use the [dangerouslySetInnerHTML](https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#dangerouslysetinnerhtml) prop on a `span` element to render it as HTML:

```js
const SYMBOLS = {
  euro: '&euro;',
  sum: '&sum;'
}

const Symbol = (props) => {
  const { entity } = props

  return <span dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: SYMBOLS[entity] }} />
}

export default Symbol
```

This is working fine but it doesn't feel right to wrap the symbols in an 'unnecessary' `span`. So has someone an idea how I could render an HTML symbol in React without using extra wrappers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`dangerouslySetInnerHTML` is the standard way to deal with raw HTML in React.

It should be avoided, but the way to do that is to avoid using raw HTML.

Type a `€` or use the JavaScript escape sequence: `"\u20AC"`

```
const SYMBOLS = {
  euro: "\u20AC",
  sum: '∑'
}
```

Sites like [File Format Info](https://www.fileformat.info/) are a good source to identify the correct escape sequence or to get a character you can copy/paste.

Comment: Ahah you right why not directly return the symbol like `€` or `∑`. It's obvious thanks for enlighten me ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can show symbol in JSX but in your code that is not correctly parsed.
You should use `ReactHtmlParser` package to parse your SYMBOL[entity] on JSX
Try to install this package.

```
npm install "react-html-parser" --save
```

This is complete code of your Symbol component

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactHtmlParser from "react-html-parser";
const SYMBOLS = {
    euro: '&euro;',
    sum: '&sum;'
  }
  
const Symbol = (props) => {
    const { entity } = props;
    return (
       {ReactHtmlParser(SYMBOLS[entity])}
    );
}
  
export default Symbol;
```

And use Symbol code

```
<Symbol entity="euro" />
```

Comment: Thanks for the help but in your example the symbol still wrapped in a `h1`.

Comment: Oh yeah! we dont have to use h1 to wrap. I updated answer and it is fully working. You can just paste string of symbol or raw code inside that object then ReactHtmlParser will parse fully. :)